# JQueryUI autocomplete doesn't update its data-attribute from the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ex6uk9/4/)

```
$('select').change(function(){
      $('#auto').attr('data-id',$(this).val())
})

$('#auto').autocomplete({
    delay: 1000,
    source: function( request, response ) {  
            alert($(this.element).data('id'))
            return false
    }
 })

<select name="category">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<input id="auto" data-id="A" type="search"/>
```

I want to update the auto-input data attribute when someone select an option in the selectbox.

Is there any way to prevent the auto-complete input from caching its data attribute? The input is able to update the `data-id` the first time I change the option from A to B in the selectbox. But when I change from `B` to `C`, the input is still alerting `B` instead of `C`. Is `$(this.element).data('id')` not an appropriate way of getting the latest data attribute?

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

what about picking the value directly from the select control, like this:

```
$('#auto').autocomplete({ 
   delay: 100,
   source: function( request, response ) {  
      var selected = $('select[name="category"] option:selected'), 
          isSomethingSelected = selected.length == 1,
          selectedVal = isSomethingSelected ? 
                        selected.val() :  
                        $('select[name="category"] option:first').val();
      alert(selectedVal);
      return false;
   }
});
```

see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ex6uk9/7/)